# Two files with same coordinate systems should overlap but don't

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcmap, shapefile

I'm a complete beginner and I have been trying to solve this problem for hours now without success. I know there are other questions like this one and I've tried to apply the answers to my problem, but just don't seem to be working. So I have a TIFF file which is a map of my country and a shapefile which contains coordinates. Both files are in the same coordinate system - MGI 1901 Slovene National Grid, but they just don't overlap in ArcMap.

I tried Project and Define projection tools to try and change the coordinate system of the shapefile with my coordinates, but nothing works. If it helps - in QGIS they overlap perfectly without any kind of manipulation beforehand.

Does anyone have any idea of what else I can try?

Comment: Be sure you TIFF has been actually geolocated and has a GCS and isn't a TIFF of a map in Slovene Nation Grid projection. Open your files in Catalogue, check the metadata, does it report a geographic coordinate system? Open the properties of each layer in ArcMap, what does it report the coordinate system as?

Comment: Thank you both for your replies. 
Dan C: Thank you for the link, I have checked it previously, but couldn't resolve my issue with the information there.
RomaH: Thank you! I have checked and if I go to the properties of the TIFF file it says that it is in MGI 1901 Slovene National Grid. And it says the same for the shapefile that contains my coordinates. I don't know what the issue is. If I try to map them both in QGIS it works, but only because I set the shapefile to 4326 WGS 84. If both files stay in MGI 1901 Slovene National Grid I can't get them to overlap (in QGIS).

Comment: Also, if I try to set the shapefile in ArcMap to 4326 WGS 84 it says that I also have to specify the geographic transformation and I don't know what to put there. If I try converting without specifying it I have no success in overlapping the two files. I'm sorry, I'm just a complete beginner with GIS and don't know what the problem could be here.

Comment: If forcing EPSG4326 coordinate system onto your shapefile causes the points to align with your expected projection, it could be a mismatch between how the coordinates are actually stored in the shapefile and how the metadata claims it is stored; it may just need to be reprojected or have its metadata updated. It is hard to speculate without actually seeing the data though.

Comment: Thank you for your insight! Actually I just tried adding the data now by using Add XY data and there I specified this 4326 WGS 84 coordinate system and it worked (somehow doing this with Project tool didn't work), my coordinates are now in the map. I hope that analysis will be accurate from now on. Do you happen to know if it is possible to have some kind of mistakes when measuring for example distances etc. if I somehow forced the wrong coordinate system onto my file?